# Creating a plotly choropleth based on a geojson

Tags: python, plotly, geojson

Can't figure out why my code is not showing the geojson (just the basic map of the world).

What am I doing wrong?

geojson file is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/isellsoap/deutschlandGeoJSON/main/4_kreise/2_hoch.geo.json

```
import json
import pandas as pd

geoJSONFile = projectFolder+'geoJSON/DE-kreise.geo.json'
with open(geoJSONFile) as response:
    polygons = json.load(response)

df = pd.DataFrame([{'fips':1,'unemp':2.4,
                   'fips':2,'unemp':5.4,
                   'fips':3,'unemp':3.4,
                   'fips':4,'unemp':7.4,
                   'fips':5,'unemp':9.4,
                   'fips':6,'unemp':0.4,
                   'fips':7,'unemp':10.4,
                   'fips':8,'unemp':5.4}])

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=polygons, locations='fips', color='unemp',
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           range_color=(0, 12),
                           #scope="europe",
                           labels={'unemp':'unemployment rate'}
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Comment: the geojson is for regions in Germany.  fips is used to identify areas in USA.  Is this what you mean?  or are you looking for a way to associate German unemployment data with German areas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you have stated that *geojson* you want to use are regions in Germany based on shared URL in question
- normally *fips* is used to identify an area in the US.  I have still used it in construction of a dataframe that uses the *ID_3* property in the *geojson* domain
- the answer really is **featureidkey** argument.  This defines the property in *geojson* that is used to match to the **locations** argument value
- there was an issue with you dataframe construction, so I generated another one to make this example work

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px


# df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv",
#                   dtype={"fips": int})
polygons = requests.get(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/isellsoap/deutschlandGeoJSON/main/4_kreise/2_hoch.geo.json"
).json()


# generate some data for each region defined in geojson...
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"fips": range(1, 434, 1), "unemp": np.random.uniform(0.4, 10.4, 433)}
)

fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    geojson=polygons,
    locations="fips",
    featureidkey="properties.ID_3",
    color="unemp",
    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
    range_color=(0, 12),
    # scope="europe",
    labels={"unemp": "unemployment rate"},
)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0})
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)
fig.show()
```

[image]